# Make a extension method appear in the 'Common' suggestion list instead of 'All' list?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, intellisense, visibility

I'm not sure whether the programmer can take precedence over Intellisense in this way.

Exists a method attribute (or a different solution) to let *IntelliSense* display a custom extension method in the **Common** suggestion list instead of the **All** list?.

[image]

### Update

Just to show an example, this is the extension, which, before I did the question, it follows @Hans Passant suggestion but it is shown in the **All** list

```
Public Module StackExtensions

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    <Extension>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Sub PushRange(Of T)(ByRef sender As Stack(Of T), ByVal items As T())

        For Each item As T In items
            sender.Push(item)
        Next item

    End Sub

End Module
```